# Video poster image not working

Tags: jquery, html5-video

Using this video background js: http://fiddle.jshell.net/mgmilcher/8R7Xx/

However the poster image does not display if the browser doesnt play video (ie mobile), just shows an empty black box. If i remove the hidden class from the poster and comment out the css here:

```
.no-video .video-container video,
.touch .video-container video {
  /*display: none;*/
}
```

It displays under the video box, then jumps to fill the area, as it should as soon as you scroll. Can anyone point me in the right direction to get the poster image working properly so it displays by default as the video would on mobile devices and non-supported browsers?

Comment: That's too much code on the jsfiddle. Can you reduce it to the minimum needed to explain your problem?

Comment: Also, not clear on why you're not just using the poster attribute of the video element.

Comment: The problem is that mobile devices just display a black box where the video should be. I guess the real question is a fallback image for mobile devices

Comment: Turns out it was a conflict with bootstrap using .hidden {visibility: hidden} instead of display: none;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a conflict with bootstrap using .hidden {visibility: hidden} instead of display: none;